# Knex query builder `where` and `andWhere` difference added conditionally?

Tags: knex.js

I need to add multiple where statements to knex query builder and confused about `where` and `andWhere` difference.

```
const qb = this.query();

if (userId) {
  qb.where('user_id', userId);
}

if (bookId) {
  // what is the difference?
  // qb.where('book_id', bookId);
  qb.andWhere('book_id', bookId);
}
```

1. If i use `where` in second condition, will it rewrite `user_id` condition? or it will rewrite it only for the same key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my experience, adding a second .where() clause automatically uses 'AND' to connect with the first .where(), so is effectively the same as using .andWhere(). But this is not documented, so you may not want to rely on the behavior.

As an aside, I often add the following clause to the query execution when validating my code to allow me to see the generated SQL.

```
/* your code above */
.on('query', function(data) {
    // outputs the SQL query you generated & runtime data bindings.
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: I can confirm that `.andWhereXXX()` and `.whereXXX()` are aliases of the same methods.

Comment: Alias in the source code: https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/8835d226529f8aebaa91c6ec77ccab47defef713/lib/query/querybuilder.js#L1706